# MySQL service does not start

Tags: mysql, debian, cluster, debian-wheezy

My MySQL service is not starting. I am using debian wheezy as operating system in my VPS. I use MyISAM for storing tables.

Response when starting service

```
root@ipxweb1:~# service mysql start
[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

The following error is showing up when I used mysqld command.

```
root@ipxweb1:~# mysqld
120811 22:06:39 [Warning] option 'thread_stack': unsigned value 65536 adjusted to 131072
120811 22:06:39 [Warning] ignore-builtin-innodb is deprecated and will be removed in future releases.
120811 22:06:39 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120811 22:06:39 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
120811 22:06:39 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
120811 22:06:39 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
120811 22:06:39 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
120811 22:06:40 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Got error 5 from storage engine
```

**EDIT:**

I am running a load balanced server, using glusterfs for replication. /var/lib/mysql directory is replicated across 2 servers. The MySQL starts perfectly fine on second server. It was working fine on first server. One fine morning, without my intervention, it happened.

Comment: post your complete my.cnf configuration here

Comment: Check the permissions of the files in `/var/lib/mysql`.  Is everything owned by the mysql user?

Comment: Yes. Everything is owned by mysql user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ perror 5
OS error code   5:  Input/output error
```

Time to check your disks....

Since it's a (most likely leased) VPS, you can't really check the server's disks, though. You may have to ask the hosting provider to look into it.

Comment: Let me ask my VPS provider for that. But, how can I confirm that the problem is with disk itself?

Comment: Please provide the output of dmesg. I'd check glusterfs before contacting the vps provider.

Comment: dmesg Does not show any output. May be if it is on a VPS?

Comment: I checked with the provider. They are saying no corruption occurred.